# MercadoPago (IPN) Payment Notifications URL rejected by payment platform

Tags: php, rest, http, mercadopago

Im trying to integrate MercadoPago on a website, everything seems fine with the Checkout options and i perceive the paymenst perfectly on my MercadoPago accounts.

The problem comes when i try to use the [IPN Pyament Notifications (Notificaciones de pago (IPN))](https://www.mercadopago.com.ar/developers/es/api-docs/basic-checkout/ipn/)
The MercadoPago site asks me to register the URL So it can send me the notifications, and when I do it it shows me the following error:

[image: Error Screenshot]

Anyway, if I make a request to the same URL from a REST client the code received is ALWAYS 200OK.

The client code Im using is the same of the [MercadoPago site's example](https://github.com/mercadopago/sdk-php/blob/master/examples/instant-payment-notifications/receive-ipn.php).

Any idea where is the problem here? Im following step by step the documentation and I cant figure out why this happens.

Thank you ver much for your time!

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
if (!isset($_GET["id"]) || !ctype_digit($_GET["id"])) {
    http_response_code(400);
    return;
}else{
    http_response_code(200);

}
```